# Ignoring all files with extensions .aux, .log in entire directory tree

Tags: git

I have many files in my directory (which contains subdirectories) containing files resulting from latex compilations like *.aux, *.log etc.

In `.gitignore` how do tell git to ignore files having extensions.aux or .log wherever they might be in a directory tree?

Comment: have you tried plain old-school wildcard matching (`\n` means newline)
`*.aux \n
*.log` etc. in your repository top dir (or wherever it applies) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put these two lines in a `.gitignore` file within your directory:

```
*.aux
*.log
```

Fyi, git has a [public documentation on `.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) and other functions.